# sort pipe delimited file with empty columns

Tags: linux, sorting, unix

I am getting an issue using sort and I believe it is due to an empty column before the column I am sorting on. I ran a sort on the file `sort -n -t'|' -k4 testme -o testedsort`, here's the output of testedsort

```
N|N||+006422931|+000359029|OVERLAY 
N|N|A|+000000020|+000000000|580    
N|N|A|+000000020|+000000020|705    
N|N|A|+000008035|+000000000|800    
N|N|A|+000009701|+000000000|723    
N|N|A.|+000009701|+001569434|742   
N|N|A|+000009701|+001569434|742    
N|N|A|+000013723|+000000000|DLORGN 
N|N|A|+000020963|+000000020|729    
N|N|A|+000022110|+004066830|GRANT
```

It appears that everything is fine except the first record, and the only thing peculiar about it is that we have an empty column. Has anyone seen this and are there any suggestions on how to fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Two things to fix

1. Assuming you are looking to sort by the fourth field only, specify the sort key as `-k4,4`
2. To handle leading `+` sign in numbers, use `-g` instead of `-n` (possibly GNU `sort`-specific)

   ```
   sort -k4,4g -t'|' testme -o testedsort
   ```

Comment: It appears that -n handles the plus sign fine. I will try the -k4,4 but I'm wondering what the ,4 means?

Comment: Well I'll be damned, the issue was the -n, I switched it to use -g and it worked.

Comment: @Serge, great that it worked for you! You need to pass key start and key end positions both via `-k`. In doing `-k4`, you are passing in just the key start, which means `sort` treats the remainder of the line as key. Probably not material for numeric sorting since `sort` would end the key when it encounters the first non-numeric character (`|` in this case) but worth adopting as a best practice